# Getting maximum update when creating countdown timer and using data from redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

can you guys help me with this? I want to render my countdown timer HH:MM:SS. However, my data to the state. My setInterval was working but when I tried to add setState and pass the data for rendering it gives me an error.  `Unhandled Rejection (Error): Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

**Also, here's my code:**

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(questActions.getAll());
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll(1, 100000));
        this.getTimeRemaining();

        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
                this.getTimeRemaining();
        }, 1000)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval)
    }

    getTimeRemaining() {
        const { quests } = this.props || {}
        const questLists = quests?.items?.items;
        let today = moment();
    
        if (typeof questLists !== 'undefined') {
            questLists.forEach(questTimer => {
                let currentDate = today;
                let expiredDate = moment(questTimer.expiresAt);
                let timeRemaining = duration(expiredDate.diff(currentDate))

                let hours = timeRemaining.hours();
                let minutes = timeRemaining.minutes();
                let seconds = timeRemaining.seconds();

                //Adding to array to render display
                questTimer.hours = hours;
                questTimer.minutes = minutes;
                questTimer.seconds = seconds;

                this.setState({
                    hours,
                    minutes,
                    seconds
                })
                
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any logic in a `componentDidUpdate` function? That's usually where this error originates. Can you update question to include full, complete component code?

Comment: That's the full code that I'm using. 

Also, the only missing are the state. this.state ={ 
hours: 0,
minutes: 0,
seconds: 0 }

Comment: Do you have any logic in *some* componentDidUpdate function? Doesn't have to be *this* component. Can you try to explain what your code it attempting to do? I don't understand why you mutate the props object via mutating `questTimer`, and why the repeated `setState` within the `forEach`, each iteration just overwrites the previous queued state update so only the last element (`questTimer`) in the array actually updates state. Can you include the parent component code that is passing `quests` prop?

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop. You are probably doing some things when the component updates on hours, minutes or seconds. Also, you are calling the setState function every single second. Are you sure you want to call `setInterval` ? What is the purpose behind this to connect to the redux store every single second to make a dispatch? Maybe a `setTimeout` will be suffice?

Side note:
If something updates in the redux store, you don't need a dispatch to get its value. It can also be passed as a `prop` to your component and your component will update itself.